# Command Argument in Runtime created imagebutton doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, imagebutton

Hello i am creating new image button something like this ;

```
e.row.cells[0].text= string.empty; //clearing the cells
Imagebutton img1= new ImageButton();
img1.Id="imgInput";
img1.ImageUrl="~/sample.jpg";
img1.CommandArgument= varID; // fetching the ID
img1.click+= new ImageClickEventHandler(imgInput_Click);
e.row.controls.add(img1)
```

I have written the above code in gridview rowdatabound event which.

Now in the click event (imgButton_Click; handled in second last line) i wish to put the command argument value in session;

```
protected void imgInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["idvalue"]= imgInput.CommandArgument; 
}
```

But the varID here is coming as null. Why so? What am i missing here?

Please guide! Thanks

Comment: excuse me for silly mistakes.. i have written program by myself & not copy-paste..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [ImageButton.Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.command.aspx) event.

**Example:**

```
  img1.Command += ImageButton_OnCommand;

  protected void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     if (e.CommandName == "Sort" && e.CommandArgument == "Ascending")
        Label1.Text = "You clicked the Sort Ascending Button";
     else
        Label1.Text = "You clicked the Sort Descending Button";
  }
```